# Remote Desktop messing up clipboard

Tags: desktop, rdp

I have a third party application that sometimes hangs (no crash just taking 100% CPU). I think this hanging is related to remote desktop (specifically the rdpclip.exe task) sometimes messing up / locking the clipboard. As this is very difficult for me to reproduce for me, I as wondering if anyone is aware of the remote desktop clipboard issue and knows what exactly is happening when rdpclip.exe messes up the clipboard (it seems to be relatively common, happening a maybe once a week). Ideally I would like to write a little programm that replicates this issue so that I can reproduce my application hanging problem at will.

Would be very grateful for any pointers you could give me.

Thomas

Answer (score 2):

According to [Microsoft](http://web.archive.org/web/20100217022822/http://blogs.msdn.com/rds/comments/1089729.aspx) this is usually related to a bug in the clipboard view chain. Sometimes application registered into the clipboard chain are terminated without getting unregistered which leaves all other applications in the clipboard chain without that change event.

I would start by trying to replicate that behaviour.

(The usual workaround is to kill the task for rdpclip which are discussed in lots of other threads)

Comment: please reference Microsoft bug!

Comment: Added the link which is to an archived Microsoft blog.